# SSL SpringBoot App Docker container behind Nginx Proxy

Tags: java, spring, docker, nginx, spring-boot

I have a Docker container, with spring boot microservice.

Also I have a Docker container, with jwilder/nginx-proxy configured with SSL working fine. The idea is to do a proxy with SSL.

[image: Docker NGINX PROXY]

But when i try call spring boot microservice I get next error:

[image: SSL Nginx]

Is necesary to do SSL configuration in the SpringBoot App too ?

Like this ?:

```
server.port: 443
server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: mypassword
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

Default.conf Nginx file (Autogenerated by Nginx Docker image).

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem;
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header
map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;
resolver 10.12.149.2;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
# Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
}
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/default.key;
}
# app.example.com
upstream app.example.com {
                                ## Can be connect with "bridge" network
                        # crdx_app-test
                        server 172.18.0.2:80;
}
server {
        server_name app.example.com;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        server_name app.example.com;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:!DSS';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/app.example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/app.example.com.key;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
        location / {
                proxy_pass https://app.example.com;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and it is very simple.
Both containers, the Nginx and the container of the application, must be under the same network, which should not be the default one.

For example:

Nginx Container

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --network="mynetwork" -v /path/to/certs:/etc/nginx/certs -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
```

App Container

```
docker run -p 8080 --network="mynetwork" -e VIRTUAL_HOST=app.example.com --name ssl_test -d sslapptest
```

This way SSL works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

> Is necessary to do SSL configuration in the SpringBoot App too ?

No. As long as you are sure that the nginx to spring boot network cannot be listened or tampered with by any other party you don't have to enable SSL on your spring boot app.

### Then why nginx is giving 503.

I don't know the answer until I see your nginx config. Most likely, your nginx config has some issues. This [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) may help you to set up nginx reverse proxy with SSL termination.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I've added the default.conf nginx config file. Is autogenerated by jwilder/nginx-proxy docke images when app container is up.