# https spring app running on docker

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, ssl, https

My issue in the last couple of days is that I'm trying to encrypt some of my projects that I'm working on. 
Since Docker is a great solution for me (if it runs locally it will run remotely) to my understanding I got 3 layers that I can implement my ssl certificate. 
First layer is the instance or the VM in my case its locally, aws or google. second layer is the Docker daemon ( that acts as a server or the manager of all containers running )and the last layer is the spring boot app or services that run on jdk-alpine environment (probably tomcat server ..).

To encrypt the app and run it through my inteliJ everything goes well and I get a secured app connection. once I build my docker file containing my jar app and running it with this line :

> docker run -p 443:8443 myImage

I get the error message:

> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

no matter what port I define in the spring boot application.properties

```
#HTTPS
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store: https-key.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password: password
server.ssl.keyStoreType: JKS
server.ssl.keyAlias: https-key
```

I get the same message that the port is been used means there is something that I'm missing.

Any help/guides to implement an https:// connection to a spring boot app that runs on Docker will be a great boos to my work and I'll appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've configured Spring Boot with SSL in the past. It worked, however I found a much more flexible, well documented and faster solution (also from a performance perspective) was to add `nginx`.

Nginx can act as a *reverse proxy*, so that when the user requests `example.com:443` SSL will be terminated by `nginx` and forwarded to your Spring Boot application listening on `8080` not exposed to the outside world. e.g.

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name example.com;
   ssl_certificate /path/to/cert;
   ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://spring_boot_application;
}

upstream spring_boot_application {
    server spring_boot_application:8080;
}
```

There is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459941/ssl-springboot-app-docker-container-behind-nginx-proxy) from someone doing the same thing, both using `docker`.

Comment: I tried the tutorial and run into some issues but figured them out except that now all I can see is the Nginx html index file but not my actual app ... but it made things much clearer to me now .. need to dig some more how to configure a Nginx container and get it right . tnx :)

Comment: @ndrzhr thanks is given by an upvote or accepting the answer.

Comment: At this time, this tutorial was deleted by the author.